# Make google maps consume 100% height and width of column?

Tags: css, google-maps

I have a 2 col layout and want my google map to take up the full height and width of one of them, this seems to work fine in chrome but in firefox the map just doesn't seem to appear? Can anyone advise on how to make this work?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r2zqg/

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.col {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.col:first-child {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed animi aliquam quae voluptates nam obcaecati harum similique sit vel molestiae. Dolor quam eum reiciendis quibusdam soluta dolore aspernatur voluptatem adipisci!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div id="map-canvas"></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column doesn't have a height.

[working (in firefox) fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2zqg/9/)

```
.col {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```